# Python debugging code which uses sys.settrace

Tags: python, debugging, pdb

Is it possible to set breakpoints in code which uses sys.settrace itself? For example, an instruction tracing program or a class that extends Pdb or Bdb

Example Code trace.py:

```
import sys

def tracefunc(frame, event, arg):
    print(event) #break here?
    return tracefunc

if __name__ == '__main__':
    if len(sys.argv) < 2:
        print __doc__
        exit()
    else:
        file_name = sys.argv[1]

    sys.settrace(tracefunc)
    globals = {}
    locals = {}
    try:
        execfile(file_name, globals, locals)
    finally:
        sys.settrace(None)
```

A simple file to trace: loop.py

```
a = 100
b = 1000
for i in range(3):
    a = a + b
    b = b + 1
```

Console output from running python trace.py loop.py

```
call
line
line
line
line
line
line
line
line
line
line
line
line
return
```

running:

```
python -m pdb trace.py loop.py
b 4 #sets a breakpoint on line 4 ie the print(event) line
s   # step through the program line by line
```

pdb never stops at line 4, but the console output shows that it was executed after line 18 execfile(...

Comment: Did you try it? What is the behavior observed?

Comment: Attaching a debugger using PyCharm, and setting a breakpoint at line 4, the breakpoint is never hit
If you run "python -m pdb ExampleCode.py SomeotherPythonScript.py" and set a breakpoint on line 4, it is also never hit. 
The console will print something like:
call
line
line
return

Depending on the other file's content, so the trace function is running and performing correctly

Comment: Added more details to the question